# Firebase - How to delete many entries at once?

Tags: android, firebase

How do I delete **all** entries for the given push ID?

For example, let's say `KoxoxwTqfb50E1Gvi9F` push ID is in many locations of my database i.e. under many keys and I want to delete all entries for `KoxoxwTqfb50E1Gvi9F` at once as opposed to statically deleting all entries (since I know their locations).

In other words, is there a way to tell Firebase "delete all entries for `KoxoxwTqfb50E1Gvi9F` across the entire database"?

Comment: None that I would've heard of. What exactly is the necessity in your case? Do you want to keep things simple on the client-side? Do you just want to make sure everything is deleted?

Comment: You have to know all the locations where something can appear and manage them all yourself.  The database doesn't understand the structure of your data - it's just a container for you to do whatever you want.

Comment: I'm not sure if this possible without a custom function. You could look into Firebase Functions, with which you could create a listener for a particular location and then have it delete all other values of the same key.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to delete multiple entries from your database, you need to know all those locations (refernces). So with other words, in the way you add data, you should also delete it.

Assuming your database looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- Users
   |     |
   |     --- userUid1
   |     |      |
   |     |      --- //user1 data
   |     |
   |     --- userUid2
   |            |
   |            --- //user2 data
   |
   --- Groups
         |
         --- groupId1
         |      |
         |      --- //group1 data
         |      |
         |      --- Users
         |            |
         |            --- userUid1: true
         |            |
         |            --- userUid3: true
         |
         --- groupId2
                |
                --- //group2 data
```

I suggest you using the method below:

```
private static void deleteUser(String userId, String groupId) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("/Users/" + userId + "/", null);
    map.put("/Groups/" + groupId + "/Users/" + userId + "/", new HashMap<>().put(userId, null));
    //other locations
    databaseReference.updateChildren(map);
}
```

This method atomically deletes all those entries. Using these paths, you can perform simultaneous updates to multiple locations in the JSON tree with a single call to `deleteUser()` method. Simultaneous deletes made this way are atomic: either all updates succeed or all updates fail.

Hope it helps.

Comment: is there a need for a push key to do simultaneous updates?

Comment: @DragonFire No, the push() method is needed when adding data, not when updating data because it creates a new random key everytime it is called. In order to create an update, you need to know all node names, you don't need to create new ones.