# How to Rollback Changes in Firebase Realitime Database - Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to rollback all Firebase realtime database changes when the user terminates the application without completing the task.

I have a complex database and I can't simply reset the values.

Comment: Please provide broad details about what data you want to rollback and provide some code what have you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, there is no need for a rollback or to reset the values. You can simply commit all task operations **only** when the last task is completed. So the simplest solution I can think of, is to use multi-location updates, which means that you can add to a map all required tasks. If the last task is also completed by the user, update all operations at once as explained in my answer from the following post:

- [Firebase - How to delete many entries at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284468/firebase-how-to-delete-many-entries-at-once/45285242)

Comment: Maybe committing the data at last stage is good idea, but in my case this isn't convenient at all. But after long search and spending more than a day I didn't found any satisfactory solution. By the end of the day I gave up and committing the data when user completes the task. BTW thanks for the help :)