# Push multiple child node in single Firebase Realtime API call?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
"categories" : {
    "-MQJLf_hh8bwY_NiA2ev" : {
      "title" : "category 1", 
      "pictures" : {
        "-MQvE-E7KyBdYuXFNa5a" : true,
        "-MQvG_HV3IIo_G7LX97C" : true
      }
    },
    "-MQJLlTdMQvI6AMwLqw8" : {
      "title" : "category 2",
      "pictures" : {
         "-MQvE-E7KyBdYuXFNa5a" : true,
         "-MQvG_HV3IIo_G7LX97C" : true
      }
    },
    "-MQJLmnwzXaEbLibMOZl" : {
      "title" : "category 3",
      "pictures" : {
         "-MQvE-E7KyBdYuXFNa5a" : true,
         "-MQvG_HV3IIo_G7LX97C" : true
      }
    }
}
```

My `categories` node likes this. Each time I want to insert some `Category` objects I have to call multiple APIs in a loop to insert each `Category` object till the last. Is there any way to approach this by using only a single API call?

Comment: If you are thinking at batch writes, yes, there is a [multi-location updates option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284468/firebase-how-to-delete-many-entries-at-once/45285242), which is similar to batch writes. More info you can find also in this [article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can just push JSON objects to the firebase realtime database.
This approach won't work with the firestore database though

```
firebase.database().ref('categories/' + categoryId).set({
    ...
  });
```

In your example the keys are generated by firebase but you can just generate your own as well