# How to remove value from HashMap (No properties to serialize found)?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I've got this structure of the database:
[image]

```
-requests
    -userID
        -requests
            -requestingUserID1 : groupID1
            -requestingUserID2 : groupID2
```

How to delete specific request by HashMap's key? Let's say I have some requestingUserID, and I want to delete it. So far I've got:

```
val updates = HashMap<String, Any>()
// updates["/requests/${firebaseUser.uid}/friendId"] = FieldValue.delete() // verion 1
updates["/requests/${firebaseUser.uid}/requests.${friendId}}"] = FieldValue.delete() //version 2
// more updates

db
    .updateChildren(updates) // error occurs here
    // onCompleteListener()
```

I get the following error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue$DeleteFieldValue
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: I've updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution to delete a record from a Firebase Realtime Database is to use "removeValue()" method as shown in the following lines of code:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
val friendIdRef = rootRef.child("requests/${firebaseUser.uid}/requests/${friendId}")
friendIdRef.removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(object : OnCompleteListener<Void?>() {
    fun onComplete(task: Task<Void?>) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Item successfully deleted.")
        }
    }
})
```

The delete() method that you are using is apart of the Firestore SDK. While both databases are apart of Firebase, both are two different products, with two different mechanisms.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. This solution helps me only to execute one task, but I needed to perform many updates at once. How to accomplish that?

Comment: In that case, a **[batch operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284468/firebase-how-to-delete-many-entries-at-once/45285242)** is required. In this way, you can delete multiple items at once.

Comment: Thank you. Basically changing to `updates["/requests/${firebaseUser.uid}/requests/$friendId"] = hashMapOf(friendId to null)` works.

Comment: Yes. Good to hear that. You're very welcome, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> Iterate over the HashMap using the Iterator.hasNext() method. While
> iterating runs , check for the value at that iteration to be equal to
> the value specified. The entry value of the Map can be obtained with
> the help of entry.getValue() method. If the value matches, remove the
> entry of that iteration from the HashMap using remove() method. The
> required entry has been successfully removed.

I have mentioned a syntax below :

```
Iterator> 
    iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry entry = iterator.next();
    if (valueToBeRemoved.equals(entry.getValue())) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

remove() method syntax is:

> hashmap.remove(Object key, Object value);

Here, hashmap is an object of the HashMap class.
Remove method takes two types of parameter:

1. Key: remove the mapping specified.
2. Value : removes the mapping only if the specified key maps to the specified value.