# Saving Transactional Data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

Can we add a new child with the help of [run transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-transactions) in an Android Firebase project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we add a new child with the help of run transactions in an Android Firebase project?

Sure we can. As the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-transactions) states, if the value that we are trying to increment using transactions doesn't exist at the location we are pointing to, we can simply set it:

```
Integer currentValue = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
if (currentValue == null) {
  mutableData.setValue(1);
} else {
  mutableData.setValue(currentValue + 1);
}
```

Otherwise, we read the value and increment it.

If you don't need to read the value and you just want to increment it, you can simply use:

```
ref.child("propertyName").setValue(ServerValue.increment(1));
```

Comment: I have a main child and this main child also contain multiple sub childs how can i add this main child with its sub childs?

Comment: If you need to update multiple locations, then you should consider using [batch writes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284468/firebase-how-to-delete-many-entries-at-once/45285242).